# What would be the downsides of sharing a resource repository between three languages?

Tags: php, ruby, node.js, dependency-management

I'm working on a set of abstract API clients in PHP, Ruby, and Node.  I've built the framework to interpret a language agnostic description file in json identical to the json descriptions in the AWS Ruby SDK.

My thought is to provide the API descriptions in a resource repository and package it as a gem, node package, and composer package. Then I can make a thin client for each language and consume the same resources.

I don't have a thorough familiarity with publishing gems or node modules so I'm wondering what potential hangups I can run into trying to use the same repository across three different ecosystems.

Comment: Since `package.json`, `composer.json` and `whatever.gemspec` have different names, I personally can’t imagine any problems you could meet.

Comment: That was my thought. I'm not too sure about any limitations on package structure for included resource files though, and accessibility from other packages.

Comment: Each packager provides you an ability to specify what you want to be included in package as pedantically as you want. That said, you might list files to be included one by one. In such a case, each packager will see _only_ what it is intended to see. Virtually speaking, `.rb` file appeared in the heap of `.php`s, would not be visible for composer and vice versa.

Comment: I think it is a perfectly reasonable approach. I've considered it myself for the AWS SDK for Ruby.